# "grails test-app * " never enters breakpoints

Tags: grails, intellij-idea, spock

I run an integration test with the command "grails test-app *" .
The test runs successfully ,but never hits my breakpoints. 
I use intellij grails configuration, and press shift+F9 to debug ,yet debugging doesn't work in any way.

BuildConfig.groovy

```
grails.servlet.version = "3.0" // Change depending on target container compliance (2.5 or 3.0)
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
grails.project.work.dir = "target/work"
grails.project.target.level = 1.6
grails.project.source.level = 1.6
//grails.project.war.file = "target/${appName}-${appVersion}.war"

grails.project.fork = [
    // configure settings for compilation JVM, note that if you alter the Groovy version forked compilation is required
    //  compile: [maxMemory: 256, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],

    // configure settings for the test-app JVM, uses the daemon by default
    test: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],
    // configure settings for the run-app JVM
    run: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
    // configure settings for the run-war JVM
    war: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
    // configure settings for the Console UI JVM
    console: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256]
]

grails.project.dependency.resolver = "maven" // or ivy
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    // inherit Grails' default dependencies
    inherits("global") {
        // specify dependency exclusions here; for example, uncomment this to disable ehcache:
        // excludes 'ehcache'
    }
    log "error" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
    checksums true // Whether to verify checksums on resolve
    legacyResolve false // whether to do a secondary resolve on plugin installation, not advised and here for backwards compatibility

    repositories {
        inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins

        grailsPlugins()
        grailsHome()
        mavenLocal()
        grailsCentral()
        mavenCentral()
        // uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable remote dependency resolution from public Maven repositories
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
        //mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
    }

    dependencies {
        // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes e.g.
         runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.29'
        // runtime 'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.3-1101-jdbc41'
        test "org.grails:grails-datastore-test-support:1.0.2-grails-2.4"
    }

    plugins {
        // plugins for the build system only
        build ":tomcat:7.0.55"

        // plugins for the compile step
        compile ":scaffolding:2.1.2"
        compile ':cache:1.1.8'
        compile ":asset-pipeline:1.9.9"

        // plugins needed at runtime but not for compilation
        runtime ":hibernate4:4.3.6.1" // or ":hibernate:3.6.10.18"
        runtime ":database-migration:1.4.0"
        runtime ":jquery:1.11.1"

        // Uncomment these to enable additional asset-pipeline capabilities
        //compile ":sass-asset-pipeline:1.9.0"
        //compile ":less-asset-pipeline:1.10.0"
        //compile ":coffee-asset-pipeline:1.8.0"
        //compile ":handlebars-asset-pipeline:1.3.0.3"
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you running tests from grails console or intellij ?

Comment: i used both, same output...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are running tests from grails console, pass --debug-fork option when you start grails console. eg `grails --debug-fork` and then run tests using `test-app` command

Or simply change the debug flag to true in this line `test: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true]` inside your BuildConfig

you have to create remote debug configuration in intellij to connect to port 5005. (Run > Edit configurations > Add new configuration > remote, and change port to 5005)

When it say "`Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005`" on grails console, attach debugger from intellij using Run > Debug and select previously created remote debug configuration.

Comment: or as an alternative disable forking

Comment: so i have to run my app ,in order to do integration testing?

Comment: No you have to do just test-app

Comment: I created new grails configuration -> "test-app --debug-fork YourClassNameIntegrationSpec --verbose --echoOut" .  afterwards i created and connected using a remote configuration on port 5005. debugging WORKS on the integration test!!

Answer (score 0):

I just do this in BuildConfig and everything works like normal:

```
grails.project.fork = [
    test: false
]
```

It can go after the first `grails.project.fork` config so that it overrides.

Answer (score 0):

Yo have to comment this line in your BuildConfig.groovy

```
test: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],
```